# How to deploy docker images to deployment server using jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

How to deploy docker images to deployment server using jenkinsfile?? is there any plugin and jenkinsfile scripts to pass the deployment...

Comment: Where you want do deploy the docker image? docker-compose?kubernetes?openshift?

Comment: i wamt to deploy on centos vm

Comment: Well it would be good if you share your jenkinsfile. please hide credentials and other sensitive info from your jenkinsfile

Comment: through ssh... can u please mention the deploy(stage) scripts that how we can deploy using jenkinsfile

Comment: image_tag = 
registry = "http://ip/docker"
registryCredentialId = 'dockerhub'

pipeline {      
  agent any
stages{
   stage ('image build'){ 
     agent { label 'linux-slave-build'}     
                   steps {
                       
                         dir("${env.WORKSPACE}"){
                         sh "docker build -t ${image_tag} . "
                         sh "docker push ${image_tag}"
                         sh "docker rmi -f images ${image_tag}"
                         
                      
      }
    }
   } 
   }

Comment: i can't paste it here ... till pushing the images i am able to do .... next stage is deployment

Comment: maybe in the deploy stage you should add ```sh "docker run -d -p PORT_NUMBER ${image_tag}"```

Comment: where can i mention deployment server IP through jenkinsfile

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: i am planing to do the deployment using ansible... if you have any idea on that please advice

Answer (score 0):

what I would suggest do something like this I assume

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage ('image build and Push') {
      steps {
        sh '''
            ssh to your server with IP # I don't know how you ssh to your server just add that command here
            docker build -t ${image_tag} .
            docker push ${image_tag
            docker run -d -p PORT_NUMBER ${image_tag}
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All these commands will executed in sequence so you will not repeat sh command multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

you can install docker plugin on jenkins.
and prefer document below for write pipeline.

[docker with jenkins pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)